# Field sampling design: stratified random or transect?

Tags: data, measurements, sampling, design, historical-imagery

I am trying to understand the impact of scientific activity in a remote polar environment.

I have five locations in different parts of the region, where historic huts were placed for a couple of decades and then removed (approx. 1960s-1980s). Researchers would live in the huts and then go out and do surveys, and take measurements in the surrounding region. Each hut also has a designated site where helicopters would land and where and an outhouse was placed.

There are communities of microorganisms living in the soils, and these communities are understood to be highly vulnerable to perturbations.

My hypothesis is that due to human activity, soils in and around the footprint of the huts have more homogeneous biophysical characteristics than soils further away from the huts.

It seems there are two ways to approach this:

1) **Stratified random** Generating random sample points within the footprint and the area assumed to have human activity. This assumption would be based off of historic photographs and reports of the activities. A buffer would then be applied to create an outer ring and an equal number of samples would be randomly taken there. Each sample point could comprise multiple points in order to capture the variability of that point. Some kind of test would be run to compare differences between the in/out classes.

2) **Transect Walk** transects from starting from the center of the hut footprint or the centroid of the area assumed to have human activity. These could be three transects at three equally-spaced azimuths. Samples would be taken at regular intervals moving away from the hut area (again doing some kind of cluster at each one). This would allow me to get a sense of the gradient of change, but might make the calculation of a statistically significant difference difficult.

Please note that I have limited time and resources, so as few samples as necessary is ideal.

It also may not be possible to revisit sites, as these are highly protected areas, so adaptive sampling is likely not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the Stratified Random approach for your study:

> [Stratified random sampling](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/stratified_random_sampling.asp#ixzz4x5ecS0O3)  is a method of sampling that involves the division of a population into smaller groups known as strata. In stratified random sampling, the strata are formed based on members' shared attributes or characteristics.

For the resource you have and current data (historic photos and reports) would suit well. In addition you could use an open-source resource such as [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) to provide some visuals and conduct calculations to draw further conclusions.

[image]

[image]